# Get 404 early in HttpClient

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I am working on a Windows Universal app. I am using the `HttpClient` for network requests. Almost all the requests go to a host on local network.
Now, flow is somewhat like this:

1. Make a request to the host.
2. Check the response.

   - If response is as expected, go on with the other things.
   - If response is 404, proceed to send magic packets to achieve wake on LAN and then continue with the things.

I made some tests on my local network, and it takes almost 7 seconds to get 404 response. I would like this response to come faster so that the app can send WOL packet as soon as possible.
Is there any way to configure `HttpClient` (or any alternative) to get 404 as soon as possible?

Comment: put a breakpoint in your code that is being hit on request and investigate where and why it is consuming **7 seconds**, and you'll get a fair idea about the solution!

Comment: @Sunny There isn't much to debug. There is `client.SendAsync()` call and that takes 7 seconds to return 404. Other requests complete instantly. Probably the client makes sure that the server is indeed unavailable?

Comment: try this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841021/socket-sendasync-taking-several-seconds-to-complete

should help

Comment: If the sever is off and it cannot reply, you will not get a 404, you will get another error such as "unreachable host", or "dns cannot be resolved" and it will take longer than 7 seconds to fail, it will take up to 2 minutes.

Comment: @kiewic Erm... I just checked with an IP that doesn't exist on my network. I got status code 404 with reason phrase 'Not Found'. And 7 seconds is all it takes. Is there any other way to check if host is on network? An ARP scan would do, but I don't know how to get it on WinRT.

Comment: @Sunny Didn't really make a lot of sense to me. I'm not even sure if API that low level is accessible through app!